# How to append value to list in single cell in Pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to append a value to a list in my dataframe based on a condition.

Sample df:

| Name | List |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | [a, b c] |
| George | [d, e f] |

I want to add the values [g, h] to the list column if the name is George.

Desired output:

| Name | List |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | [a, b c] |
| George | [d, e f, g, h] |

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cutom lambda function for add values to lists by mask:

```
L = ['g','h']
m = df['Name'].eq('George')

df['List'] = df['List'].mask(m, df['List'].apply(lambda x: x + L))
print (df)
     Name             List
0   Peter        [a, b, c]
1  George  [d, e, f, g, h]
```

Or:

```
df.loc[m, 'List'] = df.loc[m, 'List'].apply(lambda x: x + L)
```

Or:

```
df['List'] = np.where(m, df['List'].apply(lambda x: x + L), df['List'])
```

Comment: which one is faster??

Comment: If the initial cells can be empty, you want `x + L if x else L` to avoid *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'*.

Comment: @jezrael My comment was already a suggestion. ;)